# For a autonomous system, if it is stable, is it uniformly stable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

For an autonomous system $\dot{x} = f(x)$, if it is stable, is it uniformly stable?

Comment: What are your definitions of each?